# How to Query rows of data?

Tags: function, google-sheets, rows

Is it possible to query rows of data in Google sheets?

```
EX:
ROW1 A    B    B
ROW2 100  100  200
```

What I want to do is to Group by ROW1, and SUM of ROW2.

Desired result

```
A   B
100 300
```

I have tried =`query(A1:C2,"select sum(A2:C2)",1)` to see if it spits any information. But all I get is #VALUE!

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered ":" at line 1, column 14. Was expecting: ")" ...
```

I am fairly new to using Query functions, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will not be possible. However, You could transpose rows to columns and pivot them inside query.

```
 =QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:C2),"select Sum(Col2) pivot Col1")
```

This will give the table you're looking for.

Comment: If it works, mark this as solution by clicking ☑✔✓✅ on the left of this post.